# How to restrict the TCP listening address of a Windows 2003 AD DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, active-directory

I have a Windows 2003 AD integrated DNS server which I want to listen for DNS traffic on adapter IP addresses only. I have followed the steps in the [technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759481(v=ws.10).aspx), however.  After I complete them and reset the DNS server, I see the UDP is only on the configured interfaces, but the TCP is still listening on all interfaces.

Here's the output of `netstat -aon | find ":53 "`

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:53             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       8040
UDP    127.0.0.1:53           *:*                                    8040
UDP    192.168.1.2:53         *:*                                    8040
UDP    192.168.2.2:53         *:*                                    8040
UDP    192.168.3.1:53         *:*                                    8040
```

And here's a screenshot of my DNS configuration:

[image]

EDIT: To be clear, my final goal is to configure a dns proxy on the server.  I want to bind it 127.0.0.7, but I cannot because the Windows DNS server is listening on that address already.

Comment: When you telnet to the socket that you supposedly blocked, do you get a reply?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unaware of any stock functionality in the DNS server to do what you want. I'd consider using Windows Firewall rules.

Edit:

I just tested binding to TCP port 53 prior to starting the DNS Server service on Windows Server 2003, and I got a result that was wholly unexpected.

I stopped the DNS Server service then used `netcat` to bind a listener to 0.0.0.0:53. I fired up a second `netcat` instance bound to the server's LAN IP address TCP port 53. I checked the output of a `netstat -a -n -o` command and found my `netcat` processes listening as-expected. Then I fired-up the DNS Server process and checked the `netstat` output again.

To my surprise, I found that the PID for `dns.exe` was listed as owning listening bindings to 127.0.0.1:53 (which I expected) and the server's LAN IP address TCP port 53, which I didn't expect. My `netcat` process was still shown with a binding to the server's LAN IP address TCP port 53, too! Yep-- it appeared that both processes had the same listening binding.

When this "double binding" situation was in effect I found that my `netcat` process (which was started first) seemed to receive the incoming TCP connections, but I didn't do enough testing to say that my results were consistent.

I think you're stuck.

Comment: Windows firewall rules will prevent anyone from connecting to TCP 53 except on the addresses I specify, but it will not free up the address range.  I want to setup a DNS proxy on the same server, which means I need to be able to bind to a TCP :53 address on the server.

Comment: You're probably stuck. How does the DNS server process act if you bind to TCP 53 before it starts? (I'm not near a computer so I can't check myself.) You might get lucky and, through service dependencies, steal the port before it loads.